# Efficiently update multiple fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Django beginner here. I have a many-to-many model and want to update multiple values at once.

This is the model (simplified):

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Players, models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

What I do right now is this:

```
for key in dict:
    change_value = Inventory.objects.get(player=player, item=key)
    change_value.count += dict[key]
    change_value.save()
```

At least on my HDD test environment this is very slow. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? In other posts it was suggested to use update instead, so this would be:

```
for key in dict:
    Inventory.objects.get(player=player, item=key).update(count=dict[key])
```

Would this be faster? Could this be improved even further by updating multiple entries at once? Also, is there an efficient way of adding multiple new entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `.filter(..)` over `.get(..)` since then the number of queries is half, so:

```
for k, v in data.items():
    Inventory.objects.filter(player=player, item=k).update(count=v)
```

Alternatively you can even perform the mapping in a single query with:

```
from django.db.models import Case, PositiveIntegerField, Value, When

Inventory.objects.filter(player=player, item__in=data).update(
    count=Case(
        *[When(item=k, then=Value(v)) for k, v in data.items()]
        output_field=PositiveIntegerField()
    )
)
```